# How to force Asp.net development server to run as a 32-bit process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, silverlight

I am having problem getting the MS Visual Studio Remote Debugger to connect to my local IE instance as it is running as a 64-bit rather than a 32-bit process.

Every time I try to run it currently in Visual Studio I get the 
`The 32-bit version of the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot be used to debug 64-bit processes or 64-bit dumps".`

error.

Investigating a bit, I think I have narrowed it down to the web asp service being run as a x64 process rather than a x86 (which both Visual Studio, and the silver light application are running as). I confirmed it as running as a 64-bit process by trying to "attach" visual studio to the process when the application was running in the ASP.Net Development Server.

In short: Is there a setting I am missing somewhere to force Visual Studio to run the ASP.Net service as a 32-bit process? I have read about using a variable in the web.config application pool to use 32-bit (via the enable32BitAppOnWin64 config option), but it seems to only work in IIS, not ASP.net Dev server.

Any thoughts?

Edit For Clarity:
I am running Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010 (which is running as a 32-bit process). Currently it is launching ASP.NET Development Server (not IIS) to host the back end web service. I am hoping I can simply "fix" this via a setting, but if not my backup would be to run IIS Express.

Comment: "local IE instance" and "web asp service" are somewhat unrelated... Please clarify which one you have trouble debugging.

Comment: Did you get custom x64 version of dev server? The one coming with VS is 32 bit (I believe it is true even for newer versions).

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I am unsure... all I know is that when I "right click" the website in Visual Studio, and "View in Browser", it starts the ASP.NET Development Server, and opens the website in a x64 browser instance. (I Confirm this by trying to "attach" to the process via Visual Studio).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov to directly answer your question, I am running everything locally. Local ASP.NET dev server, Visual Studio is running locally, and of course IE is pointed to localhost:port/webpage.aspx

Comment: Check if you somehow configure IE on your machine to use x64 version as default browser... Normally it should default to x86.

Comment: Working through changing the "Enhanced Protection" setting (need to work on group policy though :(), but it looks promising

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly you should do this:

**IIS Manager/Application Pools-> choose the correct pool for your application/Advanced Settings/Enable 32-Bit Applications->set it to true !**

I had problem like this in the past which cost me 1-2 days, hope this helps !

Check also **Project/Properties/Build/Platform target->this should be Any CPU**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However, I guess I am a bit confused... I am *not* running a full blown IIS server for my dev environment. Instead, I am simply using the ASP.Net Development server (which gets launched by Visual Studio). Digging around, I found several pointers about changing the environment on the production server, but none for configuring the ASP.Net Development server... or am I missing something?

Comment: @Aerophilic if you are not using IIS server this will not help. Do you check project/properties/Build/Platform target->this should be Any CPU. I add it to the answer too.

Comment: Yes, I have checked :(. Unfortunately, even if I just launch the site as a whole (without even running the silverlight part) it is still showing up as a x64 process when I try to "attach" to the process via Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

**TWO PLACES:**

1). Project Properties->"Web" tab->Bitness
[image]

2). Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Web Projects->(checkbox)Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express...
[image]